# Как должен выглядить идеальный tsconfig?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image: мой сонфиг)))]

Всем привет, в данный момент рефакторю проект, тут имеется вот такой вот tsconfig.
Хотел спросить, как должен выглядить идеальный tsconfig, что должно быть включено, а что нет?

Comment: Во первых, он не должен содержать скринов. Замените скрин на текст в вопросе, для этого нажмите на "править"

Answer (score 0):

Создай новый проект с помощью `create-react-app` или его аналога для твоего фреймворка. Стандартный конфиг скорее всего будет оптимальным.

Меня больше волновал вопрос "какой лучший современный линтер", остановился на [xo](https://github.com/xojs/xo)